# Operator norm of inproduct functional

Tags: operator-theory

Let $H$ be a hilbertspace, $y$ and $z$ are fixed but randomly chosen in $H.$ Then define the operator:
$ T = \langle x,z\rangle y$.

Calculate $\|T\|$.

How should I do this? So far I have $\|T\|^2 = \sup |\langle x,z\rangle|^2 \|y\|^2$ where the $\sup$ is over all vectors $x$ with norm $1.$

Edit: also having trouble calculating $A^*$, I have $A^* = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle} z$ ,but I'm not certain about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can try to find $c$ such that $\|T\|\leq c$ and $\|T\|\geq c$. Sometimes it is easier to show the two inequalities.

For $\|T\|\leq c$ you can use the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality $|\langle x,z\rangle|\leq \|x\|\cdot\|z\|$.

For $z\neq 0$ the vector $\frac1{\|z\|}z$ has length $1$ and you can use this for $\|T\|\geq c$.

Comment: Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I found: $||T|| \leq ||y||^2 ||z||^2$. Don't really see how to calculate the other one with the tip you gave...

Comment: You should check your reference. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality that $\|Tx\|=|\langle x,z\rangle|\cdot\|y\|\leq \|x\|\cdot\|z\|\cdot\|y\|$. You can deduce $\|T\|\leq \|z\|\cdot\|y\|$. The other hint says $\|T\|\geq \left\|T\frac{z}{\|z\|}\right\|$. You should be able to compute at least that ...